# Android - app export errors with proguard and google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard

I have added the latest Google Play Services to the project and now proguard is giving
me many warnings:

```
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced method 'void setShowsDialog(boolean)' in class com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.google.android.gms.common.api.d
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-07-31 17:21:50 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I have tried adding

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.*
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
```

to the proguard configuration fil but with no luck. I am targeting android 17 (4.2.2) in my app and the min SDK version is 8 (2.2 I think).

Any help solving this error will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have setup your project with Android 4.4.2 and you have "include android- support-v13.jar". I have the same problem but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add:

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

In your Proguard?
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Yes I have added and completed all the steps of adding google play services.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the google play service jar is referencing some classes from android-support-v13.jar.
So adding following line in proguard-project.txt will solve the problem:

```
-libraryjars <ANDROID_SDK_PATH>/extras/android/support/v13/android-support-v13.jar
```

You need to download this jar using Android SDK manager.